# Can not see data in the dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to use the data i import from ../Screens and map it in a dropdown list but i due to some reason the list does not appear in the dropdown. I have tried to list the data using map method but still o response

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import DropDownPicker from "react-native-dropdown-picker";
import { data } from "../Scanner";

const newData = JSON.parse(data);

const AddTemplate = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(newData);
        }}
      >
        {newData.map((item) => (
          <Text key={item.id}>
            {item.id}
            {item.title}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <DropDownPicker
        items={newData.map((item) => ({ label: item.title, value: item.id }))}
        defaultValue={null}
        placeholder="Select an item"
        containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
        onChangeItem={(it) => setSelectedItem(it.value)}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: "center",
    // alignItems: "center",
    padding: 16,
  },
  scanBtn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
    padding: 5,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});
export default AddTemplate;
```

```
The data in newData is:
[{"claims": {"age": 21, "name": "musa"}, "description": "This is object 1", "id": 1, "title": "Object 1"}, {"claims": {"age": 22, "name": "Ali"}, "description": "This is object 2", "id": 2, "title": "Object 2"}, {"claims": {"age": 22, "name": "Ans"}, "description": "This is object 3", "id": 3, "title": "Object 3"}]
```

I tried to map the data to get specific items from the array of objects but it failed to load every time